# How do I store a jscript date into an Access date/time field?

Tags: datetime, ms-access-2007, jscript

I've been trying to work this out for a while. I have a Microsoft Access 2007 database with a DATETIME field which I am trying to fill from a JScript Date object, viz

```
rs("DTField").Value = new Date();
```

I would have thought that both JScript and Access being Microsoft tools would know how to do this, but I assume too much it would seem.

What transforms do I need to apply to either side of the equation to make this value assignment work?

*Added question*:

What about going the other way, from database to JScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`getVarDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d4x3w61%28VS.84%29.aspx) function.  From the documentation:

> The getVarDate method is used when code interacts with COM objects,
>   ActiveX objects, or other objects that accept and return date values
>   in VT_DATE format. These include objects in Visual Basic and Visual
>   Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript). The actual format of the returned
>   value depends on regional settings.

```
rs("DTField").Value = (new Date()).getVarDate();
```

---

To answer your added question, you need to explicitly create a `Date` object.

```
var theDate = new Date(rs("DTField").Value);
```

Comment: Apparently not ([this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2007/12/19/date-time-formats-and-conversions.aspx) is the closest I've found to an official source).